# Making a graph for the radioactive decay affected by the reservoir effect. calculus

Tags: calculus

Suppose a bivalve shell fragment is also found to have 72% of the amount of original 14C. In this case, after doing the analysis as in part (a), an archaeologist might subtract around 440 years from the calculated age. This is to account for the fact that deep ocean water mixing with surface water produces a reservoir effect that makes fragments from aquatic organisms seem older than they actually are. In a paragraph illustrated by a well-labelled graph, explain the reservoir effect. Your graph should be of the decay curve of 14C over time, and should describe the difference between the “calculated age” and “actual age” of the shell fragment. i have done part a and obtained 2716 years.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to graph it